# Math Field doesnt recalculate when fields are populated

Tags: entities, javascript

I have 2 Select list(Integer) fields and I am using [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) to get the sum of the two fields. But when I populate the first value the field is calculated and when I populate the second field it does not recalculate. Help me please.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Stefan, please make sure you the issue you are facing is not reported in the module issue queue(https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/mathfield?categories=All), if not I would recomment you to test the module on vanilla drupal and see if issue persit if so you can create an issue on module page. Also check your also if you see any js error?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no I don't think so, that's how drupal stores the value irrespective of single valued or multivalued, but yes I am afraid there are few other open issues opened on the module page if that could help or else if its a problem not identified earlier(less like to occur) it should go on d.o.

Comment: @arpitr : you may have a valid point, but still I doubt (sorry). Just looking at the machine names of those 2 fields, one would expect (guess?) that the fabric_number is a unique value. However for field_category it could be either a single value, or a multi value (we can't tell from the info provided, I think). Or do you see anything else in the limited info provided?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens "Just looking at the machine names of those 2 fields, one would expect (guess?)"  - I would rather watch Sherlock Holmes!

Answer (score 1):

The (fairly new) [Math Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathfield) module for D7 is a not commonly known/used alternative to [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field)).

However, there are still a few other (known) issues with it, as mentioned also on its project page:

1. The cTools math expression library causes an error when using function that take more than one parameter. This effects pow(), min(), max() ([#1958538: Improve math expression engine](https://www.drupal.org/node/1958538)).
2. Math Field does not yet support multivalue options fields (checkboxes, or multiselect) ([#2483453: Add aggregate functions for multivalue fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2483453)).

However, if you're trying to use this module to handle multivalue fields, then that would explain why you can't get that to work (as per the issue mentioned before: multi value fields are not yet supported).